# $N = \dfrac{x^{n + 1} - 1}{x - 1}$ solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time solving for $x$ on the equation: $N = \dfrac{x^{n + 1} - 1}{x - 1}.$

My goal is to implement it as a python function so $N$ and $n$ can vary

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried division?

Comment: So you want to say, have n=7, N=9, and want to know what is the value of $x$?

Comment: No, there is no simple formula for this.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to say, have $n=10, N=3$, and want to know what is the value of x? If this is the case then notice that when you divide a degree $n+1$ polynomial by one of its factors, as in this case, you get a polynomial of degree $n$.

For example:

$$\frac{x^{9} - 1}{x - 1}=x^{8} + x^{7} + x^{6} + x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1$$

There is no closed form for this polynomial. If the value of $n$ is greater than $4$. To solve such forms, numerical methods would be required.

Comment: appropriate username!

Comment: @LukeCollins, After trying so hard for many years, I came to this conclusion :)